# Audio tag dowload menu not showing in the right place

Tags: html

I'm putting an audio tag in my application via php and the dowload button of the element stays off the screen, sometimes until it focuses on a part of the site and scrolls down

see an example  [The dropdow menu is on the side of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR8TG.png)

```html
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://storage-gw-br-01.voximplant.com/br06-records/2019/06/26/ZTdiZjk0YmYwNTkzZmMwOWY2NDI0ZGRlOTA2MTI1MjcvaHR0cDovL3d3dy1ici0wNi0xNDcudm94aW1wbGFudC5jb206ODA4MC9yZWNvcmRzLzIwMTkvMDYvMjYvMDdmZDc2NWM3OTViNjgzOC4xNTYxNTcxOTE1LjI5MDU5ODUubXAz?record_id=33759311">
</audio>
```

is there any way I can control this menu?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is no download button in your example. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Howdy, without a way to reproduce the issue it's rather difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that you can disable the auto generated download button and create your own by appending the anchor tag after the audio control and style it like download button. you can hide auto generated button and provide your own download button by following code :

```html
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
  <source src="https://storage-gw-br-01.voximplant.com/br06-records/2019/06/26/ZTdiZjk0YmYwNTkzZmMwOWY2NDI0ZGRlOTA2MTI1MjcvaHR0cDovL3d3dy1ici0wNi0xNDcudm94aW1wbGFudC5jb206ODA4MC9yZWNvcmRzLzIwMTkvMDYvMjYvMDdmZDc2NWM3OTViNjgzOC4xNTYxNTcxOTE1LjI5MDU5ODUubXAz?record_id=33759311" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<!-- **Adding your own download button using anchor tag** -->
<a href="--Bind your video path here via php and angular js--" download>--Place download icon here like <i class="fa fa-download"></i>--</a>
```

This will solve your issue for download context menu

Comment: maybe something in html prevents the menu from popping up on the button that calls it

Comment: Yes that can be the reason, if you think so then try to change the sizes of parent of audio tag or place it in separate div or full width container, and also let me know that you are resizing the screen width while development, that can also be the root of problem, thank you

Comment: I'm passing via php to an angularjs site

Comment: I Have edited my whole answer i think this is the best way found on internet to solve your problem and as per the google docs the `controlsList="nodownload"` is the attribute which can be used to hide the option button for audio and video controls.